# How to call a function in another MVC controller using AJAX in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My folder structure looks like this. Both of these folders are contained within the Area folder.

[image: Folder structure]

I am trying to call a function from the EmailController inside `ITRequests/Scripts/Edit.js` and it fails to find it.
The `.js` code look likes this

```
$(document).on('change', '#StatusId', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    debugger;
    if(( $('#OldStatus').val() ) != ( $('#StatusId').val()) ) //Aka if the user switched the status on submit
    {
        var status_description = [$('#OldStatus').val(), $('#StatusId').val()];
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Email/Email/statusChangeEmail",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'request': $('#RequestId').val(), 'status_descriptions': status_description }),
            done: function (data) {
                debugger;
                alert("working");
            }
        })
    }
})
```

`RequestId` is a hidden value on the page which is being picked up correctly, likewise the `status_description` field is taking the correct values and (tries to) pass them to the function.
The function `EmailController.cs` is defined as such

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult statusChangeEmail(int request, string[] status_descriptions)
    {
         //stuff happens
         return Json(1);
    }
```

However every time this happens I get this error message[image]

Comment: Can you try  url: "/Email/statusChangeEmail"

Comment: You have 1 too many `Email` in your url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why your URL is /Email/Email/statusChangeEmail? It should be /Email/statusChangeEmail.

The /Email means EmailController and /statusChangeEmail means controller action statusChangeEmail .

Comment: Wow that was an easy fix. I named it as such because the function calls to ITRequstsController functions are done in the same way. http://i.imgur.com/3lVBGW7.png why is it that these functions have ITRequests/ITRequests before the function name and still work?

Comment: You can read more about routing in http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/controllers-and-routing. Basically you can have any value to be routed to a URL.